# Python Dictionary wierd behaviour with same keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Actually i was facing a bug in my main program. On some inspection, i found some wierd behaviour with dictionaries.

Here is very basic example of this :-

```py
x,y,z = 1,1,1

dik = {x:'A',y:'B',z:'C'}

print(dik[x])
```

Expected Output : `A`

Faulty output : `C`

In my Program, the values of `x,y,z` are random one digit positive integers.

So in many cases values of x or y or z may be same.

In such cases the dictionary behaviour gets wierd.

Seems like when multiple keys have same values, python dictionaries prefer last Item with that value.

**But i don't want this.**

I don't want to use the "value" of `x` as key.

I want to use the "name" `x` as key

**In simple words :-**

Suppose i declare

`>>> x = 3`

Now i want something Like

`>>> print(getName(x))`

`x`

How can i do so ?
I know this question has been asked already but answer of that qn. Didn't work in my case

Comment: This is not weird behavior, it's what is expected to be. Can you elaborate on what/why you try to do, because this very much looks like XY problem

Comment: "I want to use the "object" `x` as key" - it sounds like you have a misunderstanding of the relationship between variables and objects in Python. You might want to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @user2357112 ok, by 'object' i meant the 'name' x

Comment: @lllrnr101 actually to bypass this behaviour i am using tuple in my main program too, it works but creates unnecessary complication

Comment: You can't use a "variable" as the key, because the hash of the key must not change. You _might_ use the string `"x"` as key and (a) drop the variable and store the value of the variable in a second dict, or (b) look up the variable value for a key in `locals`.

Comment: @buran i mean that in `dik[x]` i want python to just use the name `x` as dictionary key & not its value (i.e. 1)

Comment: @tobias_k how do i create a string from variable name. Is there any special method available in python ?

Comment: again, this looks like XY probelm. Ned Batchelder again -   [Keep data out of variable names](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html). If your key is string `'x'` what it is relation to value 1 (without the need of using e.g. `locals()`).

Comment: @buran by xy problem, are you asking to post original app code ?

Comment: I am asking to post [mre] and expalain what you try to achieve. i.e. you have a problem and you have come up with "solution" that doesn't work as you expect and most likely is plainly "bad". Here you ask how to fix the "bad" solution, but actually you need to ask how to deal with the underlying problem.

Comment: About XY problem - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Answer (score 1):

You are setting to the dictionaries repeated keys.
When you do this:

```
dik = {x:'A',y:'B',z:'C'}
```

x, y and z has the same value (1), thus that is like you are setting:

```
dik = {1:'A',1:'B',1:'C'}
```

And that's bad, because the dictionaries cannot repeat keys, so the dictionary will have the item:

```
{1: 'C'}
```

For that reason you are getting the 'C' value

Comment: I see you didn't read the whole question. I know why this is happening. To solve this : i dont want python to use the value of x (i.e. 1) as dictionary key. I want to just use x as key not it's value. Or perhaps a workaround to this situation

Comment: Sorry, I guess I understand now, maybe you should try `print(dik['x'])` but that will return a `KeyError` because with `dik['x']` is searching in the dictionary if this have the string 'x' but it's not.
If you try `dik = {'x':'A',y:'B',z:'C'}` that will work as you want.

Answer (score 1):

It feels like you're trying to represent two things with your variables. There's some numeric value assigned to the variable, and then there's a string which is kept in the dictionary. I think you'd benefit from extending your variables x,y,z to be objects:

```
class my_obj():
    def __init__(self, digit, letter):
        self.digit = digit
        self.letter = letter

x = my_obj(1, 'A')
y = my_obj(1, 'B')
z = my_obj(1, 'C')
dik = { 'x': x, 'y': y, 'z': z }
```